# String to String Type Conversion in Struts 2 not working?

Tags: java, design-patterns, encryption, struts2, type-conversion

I want to encrypt user input and store it in a database. I am using Struts 2 type conversion, all user input is treated as a `String`, and conversions such as the following work correctly:

- `String` to `Integer`
- `String` to `Long`
- `String` to `byte[]`

But when I attempt a conversion to the target type: `String`, it does not work and the `convertFromString()` method is not invoked.

```
@Override
public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] value, Class arg2) {
    String val = value[0];      

    try {
        return ASEEncDecUtil.encrypt(val.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Is there a best practice that should be used to encrypt user input?

Comment: By *user input* you mean a *password* or a *content* (eg. a text) ?

Comment: It is text content having some sensitive information that we want to encrypt .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of a Converter is to perform a conversion between different formats.

It is *not* the right tool to get an object in a format, perform a business on it and then returning it in the same format.

That said, for this kind of things you can use several mechanisms (orthogonal like Struts2 Interceptors and Java EE Decorators, or specific like Action Methods or even Mutators / Accessors), each one more appropriate according to factors like the number of times / places where you need to use them.

The easiest way (I'm a KISS paradigm fan) is the Accessors / Mutators way:

```
public class KeepItSimpleStupidAction extends ActionSupport {

    @Inject Logger LOG;

    private String text; // text is always encrypted inside the action

    public String getText() { // but it can also be read decrypted by calling the getter 
        return ASEEncDecUtil.decrypt(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    public void setText(String text) { // the setter automatically encrypts it
        this.text = ASEEncDecUtil.encrypt(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    public String execute() {
        LOG.debug("text decrypted: " + getText());
        LOG.debug("text encrypted: " + text);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are most probably extending `StrutsTypeConverter` class in your custom converter. In it the `convertFromString` and `convertToString` methods are called from the `convertValue` method which looks something like that:

```
public Object convertValue(Map context, Object o, Class toClass) {
    if (toClass.equals(String.class)) {
        return convertToString(context, o);
    } else if (o instanceof String[]) {
        return convertFromString(context, (String[]) o, toClass);
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
        return convertFromString(context, new String[]{(String) o}, toClass);
    } else {
        return performFallbackConversion(context, o, toClass);
    }
}
```

So if `toClass` is `String` class then `convertFromString` is never called.

To achieve what you want, extend `com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultTypeConverter` instead and override `public Object convertValue(Map context, Object o, Class toClass)` method.

Comment: thanks for explaining why method convertFromString() is not getting invoked.